# How to align separate equations to one side

Tags: equations, align

I'm writing several separate equations using

```
\begin{equation*}
equations in here
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
equations in here
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
equations in here
\end{equation*}
```

Each equation is long and has a series of steps involved. I have aligned each step within each equation so that each equation looks "professional". The problem when doing this is that some of the equations, themselves, start in different places depending on their length in the document. Some start a little to the left, some a little more to the right. Is there a way to align separate equations? I tried surrounding the equations with `align*`but each equation stays the same. I just want each separate equation lined up say to the left for example. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you also use the `&` sign within `align*` to specify which part should be aligned? If it still does not work, please provide a MWE _showing the error_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, for example, with the `flalign*` environment. Just surround each equation with `&`...`&`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent These are my equations

\begin{flalign*}
  &x=y&\\
  &a+b+c+d+e=f&\\
  &jk=xyz&
\end{flalign*}


\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Each equations can be inserted in a separated `flalign*`, if you want

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent These are my equations

\begin{flalign*}
  &x=y&
\end{flalign*}

\begin{flalign*}
  &a+b+c+d+e=f&
\end{flalign*}

\begin{flalign*}
  &jk=xyz&
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

---

As barbara beeton notices in the below comment, the spacing between consecutive `flalign`s is too large. To avoid that, you can redefine locally the lengths `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip`, as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent These are my equations

{\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0ex}\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{1ex}
\begin{flalign*}
  &x=y&
\end{flalign*}

\begin{flalign*}
  &a+b+c+d+e=f&
\end{flalign*}

\begin{flalign*}
  &jk=xyz&
\end{flalign*}
}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: unfortunately, the vertical space between the separate `flalign*` "groups" is too large.  i'll provide an alternate when i can get back to my workstation at the office.  (too much snow to travel just now.)